About the normal form of a repeated game
Consider an infinitely-repeated game with perfect monitoring and pure strategies. The one-shot deviation principle tells us that a strategy profile $\sigma$ is a subgame perfect Nash equilibrium if and only if there are no profitable one-shot deviations.
More precisely, let $h^t$ denote the history available to players up to the beginning of period $t$.
For each history $h^t$, let $a^*=\sigma(h^t)$. It must be that
$$
(1-\delta) u_i(a^*)+\delta U_i(\sigma|_{(h^t,a^*)})\geq (1-\delta) u_i(a_i, a^*_{-i})+\delta U_i(\sigma|_{(h^t,a_i, a^*_{-i})})\quad \forall a_i, \forall i
$$
where

$\delta$ is the discount factor

$u_i$ is the stage game payoff

$\sigma|_{(h^t,a)}$ is player $i$'s continuation strategy induced by history $h^t$ and action $a$.

$U_i$ is the continuation payoff


Question: My lecture notes say that in this setting $U_i(\sigma|_{h^t,a})$ just depends on $a$ and so can be denoted by $v_i(a)$. Hence, the normal form of this game with 2 players and 2 actions $\{0,1\}$ is
|      (1-delta)u_1(1,1)+delta*v_1(1,1)  | (1-delta)u_1(1,0)+delta*v_1(1,0)
|      (1-delta)u_2(1,1)+delta*v_2(1,1)  | (1-delta)u_2(1,0)+delta*v_2(1,0)
|----------------------------------------|----------------------------------------
|      (1-delta)u_1(0,1)+delta*v_1(0,1)  | (1-delta)u_1(0,0)+delta*v_1(0,0)
|      (1-delta)u_2(0,1)+delta*v_2(0,1)  | (1-delta)u_2(0,0)+delta*v_2(0,0)

I don't understand this step at all. In particular:
(1) The fact that I can write the normal form of a repeated game as above is a consequence of the one-shot deviation principle?
(2) Suppose in the above normal-form game, $(0,0)$ is a Nash Equilibrium for given values of $v_1, v_2$. What is the relation between such Nash equilibrium and a subgame perfect Nash equilibrium of the repeated game?
(3) Suppose in the above normal-form game, $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$  are Nash Equilibria for given values of $v_1, v_2$. Does this imply that there are multiple subgame perfect Nash equilibria in the repeated game as well?

The intuition is that, following any history $h^t$, the continuation strategy should be a subgame perfect equilibrium $\sigma|h^t$, which allows you to predict the value of continuation play ($V(\sigma|h^t)$) with certainty. Therefore, when choosing the current-stage strategy, a player know her action $a$ counts toward $h^t$, which in turn, leads to $\sigma|h^{t-1}\cup\{a\}$, generating a certain continuation payoff $v_i(\sigma|h^{t-1}\cup\{a\})$. And because other things are already determined, you can simply write $v_i(a)$. This is precisely why the continuation payoff is in fact history-strategy dependent.
The normal form says the players are choosing today's strategy $a$ by trading off today's payoff $u_i(a)$ and (discounted) future valuation $v_i(a)$. You can use the normal form because everything can be summarised into a current-stage variable $a$.
Edits:
Question (1): you are right, there're infinitely many strategies for each player. However, to deal with this repeated game, we conjecture that there is some SPE $\sigma$ being played following action $a$. One-shot deviation principle makes it clear you never deviate from $\sigma$. Think it as some black-box algorithm that automatically choose the best action for you forever, after your play for the current period. In this sense, any future strategies are summarized by the current action $a$, and $U_i(\sigma|(h_{t-1}, a)$ is function of only $a$ but not anything else, so you can relabel it as $v_i(a)$.
Question (2): Then the SPE of the repeated game contains $(0,0)$ as the first period strategy, e.g., Round 1: play $0$; Round 2: if $(0,0)$ was played in round 1, play $a_{(0,0)}$, otherwise...
Since it's an infinitely repeated game, you should have one SPE where $(0,0)$ is played every period. E.g., infinitely repeated prisoner's dilemma, you have (confess,confess) to be played ``no matter what'' as an SPE, but you can also have grim trigger -- (deny, deny) is a Nash equilibrium in your normal form, and for next period, if (deny, deny) is played, then continue (deny, deny); otherwise, (confess, confess) forever.
Question (3): Yes. From the logic above, you should see there can be infinitely many SPE.

Thanks DiZ. First, you made me realise that I forgot to add $a$ in the continuation strategy, I've edited my question. Still, I do not understand how we go from $U_i(\sigma| (h_t, a))$ to $\nu_i(a)$. Where do $\sigma$ and $h_t$ go? Are they implicit?

I have split my questions into 3 subquestions. If you could answer those, in particular (3), it would be very helpful.

Hi Star, thanks for clarifying. Just edited my original answer.

Thanks, but your answers do not seem to match my questions

Sorry for the confusion, I have edited my answers to those questions.
